# Sublime-text3 highlights a } as an illegal character

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

Why does my `sublime-text3` text editor highlights the closed parenthesis as an illegal character while the code compiles?

```
{
    cout<<">>"<<endl;   
}
```

Is it related to digraphs or trigraphs?

[image: s]

Comment: What is the "sublime-text3"?

Comment: There are neither trigraph nor digraph symbols.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it is a [text editor](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it is a bug of Syntax Highlighting. Looks like it has been fixed, but it is raised quite recently(in Sep 2019) so it probably is not reflected in your version. I tested it and had same issue with *Build 3211* which is the lastest offical version.

Here's the [issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/2042) and [fix](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/2079) for that. You may try the recent `C++.sublime-syntax` file.

Comment: nice find! since its related to template parsing, I found something as simple as `a < ">"` also triggers it :p